# How to call control from Razor view

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on mobile website and I use razor engine I created my code to retrieve fields from DB where ID .I added default value for ID but I want the ID from hidden control .

view:

```
 <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
      @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.ID)
        <div class="editor-label ">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field create-Bt3">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field create-Bt3">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="create-Bt ">
                <input type="submit" value="Insert" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoginIndex(string Role)
{
    var data = db.Login.ToList();


    if (Role == "DataEntry")
    {
        Response.Redirect("../Category/Index");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("../Login/Index");
    }
    return View();



}
```

Comment: So... what's the question?

Comment: Your question is not clear. There is no relation between view and action method. In your view you used a model, and you passed a string your action.

Comment: jquery. $('#ID').text...

Comment: The controller portion of your example is unnecesary, since the question seems only Razor syntax / MVC helper related.

Comment: If i got this right, you're confusing the `ID` property on your domain objects with the `Id` property on the html element.

Comment: Is that Hidden input in the form ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set an explicit Id for an element created with `@Html.Hiddenfor`

Razor allows you to pass an object, or a `dictionary<string, object>` that sets the html parameters of the control it generates.

Using that, your code would look like this :

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.ID, new {Id="hiddenInputId"});
```

This would generate the following: (Value will probably be different from my example)

```
 <input type="hidden" id="hiddenInputId" name="Id" Value="0" />
```